# How to change access settings in IIS-7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, permissions

I have an IIS-7-hosted website which is accessible by everyone (public domain), and it has several applications inside it. But I want only some of these applications to be accessible by everyone. The others must be accessible only through my company's local network. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control access to your sites be enforcing authentication and authorization rules on your private applications.

However...

I strongly recommend running Intranet applications and Internet applications in separate IIS web sites, and use your network firewall to prevent all Internet access to your Intranet site.

Comment: which authentication/authorization rules? How do I change those?

Comment: @Raze2dust: I'd suggest reading up on Integrated Windows Authentication (if it applies to your Intranet environment), and Forms Authentication. Configuration options are available in IIS Manager, in the Authentication module (click a site, then select Authentication from the workspace pane). With authentication configured, you may find this resource useful to handle authorization: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871.

Good luck!